# Block Level back up for MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-backups, enterprise

I'm part of the development team planning a new infrastructure for new products our company is branching into.

We've decided to use MariaDB as our preferred database solution to get away from being tied to Microsoft's products. It would allows us to scale both horizontally and vertically as well as not be tied to a particular platform, and also avoids any licensing fees, CALS and so on.

However we have a decision-making level team member who is very reluctant to explore anything that isn't Microsoft based (in fact actively refuses to even look anything else) and will happily look, and usually find, something that he can use to veto using any non MS stuff.

He has now thrown at us, with regards to enterprise backups, that MariaDB is 'strangely falling short in this regard - for a supposedly highly-scalable database it seems to be missing an obvious feature' because it doesn't support/provide any block level backup solutions. He's dismissed incremental backups because 'you end up with long chains of incremental backups which extends the restore time & introduces opportunities for the chain to break'. His MS point of reference is that MariaDB doesn't support VSS, or rather can break when restoring.

So we're now trying to find a clear cut answer to this.

We don't care if it's an MS or 3rd party product or a series of Windows settings, but is there a tried, tested and trustworthy block level back-up solution available that works on Windows hosts that will allow us use MariaDB?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but incremental backups usually don't end up with "long chains" unless they aren't being done correctly. In most cases I wouldn't expect more than a weeks worth of incremental before a full dump is done.

Comment: I have to say that other team members brought up that he shouldn't be holding the back up for more than a week or two max anyway, our data is changing a lot and a month old set of data is almost worthless for us. Your comment confirms this thinking.

Comment: I have a decision making person that is much like the one you describe. It doesn't matter whether or not it's a less expensive or superior solution, if it doesn't have MS in the name he won't even consider it and shuts down any further discussion.

Comment: Yes, they sound very much the same. Either the discussion is shut down instantly or they get their way because you tire of fighting the never ending uphill battle.

Comment: Perhaps he is afraid to learn a new database product?  It is ludicrous that the discussion is stalled on such an obscure "feature".  I'm afraid that there will a hundred other "features" that don't look the same in MariaDB, hence will be considered as "deficient".  Warm up your resume.

Comment: Quite possibly. By his own admission he's never used or even considered MySQL/MariaDB or even Linux, which given his position as the decision maker for IT Operations here we find very strange. It baffles me that he's not interested in looking to see if there are any alternatives that might turn out to be better options for the company, financially or otherwise. I mean how else do you know you're providing the best solution you can? Anyway, we've gotten our way this far and we've moved to MariaDB (without the concern of 'block level' backup), and so far, it's all working perfectly!